# Dynamic table colspan

Tags: jquery

I have worked for web project and I'm using jQuery for client side scripting issues.
I have an ajax page and this page fully loading dynamically from inside of the javascript that is uses jquery.

When the document ready, i'm creating three smilar table like these;

**Table A**

Hea A | Hea A | Hea C | Hea D

**Table B**

Col A | Col A | Col C | Col D

**Table C**

Col A | Col B | Col C | Col D

After that, I'm clonning Table A then it's looking inside of the between Table A and B, if it found smilar columns it's updating Table A's columns "colspan" property. When the merging completed it's output looks like ;

**Table A**

Hea A [colspan=2]  | Hea C | Hea D

**Table B**

Col A | Col A | Col C | Col D

**Table C**

Col A | Col B | Col C | Col D

It's working on almost all browser but IE 7.0 is not.
Here is the another trick; I'm trying to run my example project, It's showing incorrect in IE 7.0 When i copy/paste output html to empty page manually, is working magically.

I stacked in that.

Any suggestion or help are welcome.

Comment: Show the code you've got so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found where is the problem. 
When browser IE 7.0 you should use `this.colSpan = value` instead of `$(this).attr('colspan', value)` for changing colspan values in the runtime.

Take a [look here](http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-en/browse_thread/thread/e8ba024a46f05f4f) for detailed information